# Substituir hífen de uma variável para capitalize no .bat

Tags: windows, batch, replace, bat

Tenho um .bat (Windows) que automatiza uns processos internos. Em um dado momento eu preciso transformar o valor de uma variável de `"foo-bar-too"` para `"FooBarToo"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resposta atualizada, veja se é isso:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:Inicio

cls
echo.
set /p "Variavel=Informe a variavel com hifens: "
IF not defined Variavel goto :Inicio

set Contador=0
set CP=1

:PegarTamanho
If "!Variavel:~%Contador%,1!"=="-" (
                                    set /a CP+=1
                                   ) else (
                                           set Palavra[%CP%]=!Palavra[%CP%]!!Variavel:~%Contador%,1!
                                          )
set /a Contador+=1
IF not "!Variavel:~%Contador%,1!"=="" goto :PegarTamanho

for /L %%a in (1,1,%CP%) do for %%b in (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z) do if /I "!Palavra[%%a]:~0,1!"=="%%b" set PalavraFinal=!PalavraFinal!%%b!Palavra[%%a]:~1!

IF "%PalavraFinal%"=="" for /L %%a in (1,1,%CP%) do set PalavraFinal=!PalavraFinal!!Palavra[%%a]!

cls
echo.
echo  Antes: %Variavel%
echo.
echo  Depois: %PalavraFinal%
echo.
pause
set PalavraFinal=
set Variavel=
for /L %%a in (1,1,%CP%) do set Palavra[%%a]=
goto :Inicio
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funciona para o exemplo acima, mas não vai funcionar se o valor da variável for outro, por exemplo: `nome-muito-importante`. 
Graças a sua resposta consegui montar a lógica na cabeça, mas ainda não sei como implementar:
1. a primeira letra sempre vou mudar para maiúscula
2. a primera letra após um hífen sempre vou mudar para maiúscula
3. após o passo 2, excluir todos os hífens

Comment: Poderia explicar a lógica então, não sabia que o bat tinha que funcionar para qualquer palavra pensei que ela não mudava

Comment: Foi falha minha, mas graças a você consegui pensar na lógica, vou editar a pergunta adicionando a lógia

Comment: favor veja a resposta atualizada...